# Two pies in the same graph - Highcharter

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I am trying to reproduce the [following example](http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/ncLfB/) of two pies in the same highchart graph with no success. An example code below. Does any one knows how to create two charts in the same chart in highcharter?

```
df = tibble(name = c("a","b","c"),
        a1 = c(10,12,11),
        a2 = c(22,23,22))
highchart() %>%
hc_chart(renderTo = "container", type = "pie") %>%
hc_add_series(df, hcaes(name, a1), size = 100, center = c(30,10)) %>%
hc_add_series(df, hcaes(name, a2), size = 100, center = c(10,30))
```

Comment: Pie chart are not optimal for visualization, see for example Steph Few [piecharts](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiL64q0n5jtAhWEqHEKHUkLAeIQFjAAegQIBBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.perceptualedge.com%2Farticles%2Fvisual_business_intelligence%2Fsave_the_pies_for_dessert.pdf&usg=AOvVaw028_adqzITh5jP7qRNOAHK). Unless you have only 2 categories and some comparison around 25% or 50%, a bar chart will be more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution

```
highcharter::hw_grid(
  hchart(df, type = "pie", mapping = hcaes(name, a1))
  ,
  hchart(df, type = "pie", mapping = hcaes(name, a2))
) %>% htmltools::browsable()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I initially thought it should be controlled by the `center` arguments as per your code above (and didn't work as you pointed out).

One workaround is:

```
highchart() %>% 
hc_add_series(type = "pie", data = df, hcaes(name, a1),size = 100, name = "test1", center = c(0, 0)) %>%
hc_add_series(type = "pie", data = df, hcaes(name, a2),size = 100, name = "test2") %>%
hc_plotOptions(pie = list(center = c(700,450)))
```

You need the `center` argument in the first series although it doesn't do anything other than fixing the first pie (changing `c(0, 0)` doesn't actually change the location of the pie)
then using `hc_plotOptions` to control the location of the second pie chart.

Comment: This worked for me when making a pie nested in a donut chart, like this one: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut